# speedtest ERROR: No matched servers: 4510 /* (4510 is the Server ID) */

Tags: server, cron, download-speed, zabbix

I want to get speedtest status on Zabbix Server so after the Readme of "Zabbix Speedtest" mentioned in the Zabbix website https://git.cdp.li/polcape/zabbix/tree/master/zabbix-speedtest

Here's the Install instruction:

1- Install the speedtest-cli (pip install speedtest-cli) and jq (yum install jq)
2- Copy the speedtest.sh to /etc/zabbix/script and make executable: chmod +x /etc/zabbix/script/speedtest.sh

3- Alternative 1: Install the systemd service and timer: cp speedtest.service speedtest.timer /etc/systemd/system and start and enable the timer: systemctl enable --now speedtest.timer

4 - Alternative 2: Use the crontab by copy the speedtest.cron to /etc/cron.d

5 - Import the zabbix-agent config: cp speedtest.conf /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf.d/

6- Restart zabbix-agent: systemctl restart zabbix-agent

7 -Import template_speedtest.xml on your Zabbix server

and runing the service i got :

[image]

I got the error:

```
No matched servers: 4510
```

Comment: Which distro and version are you running?